# how to get all possible combinations of a set of letters

Tags: r

I'd like to create all possible combinations of the set `S = { a, t, g, c }` with length 10. Thus, there will be `4^10 = 2^20 = 1048576` ways to do this.

I am looking for a solution in R. My googlefu yielded the `gregmisc` package, however I am unable to install this package due to my version of R.

```
package ‘gregmisc’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

**Update**: As an alternative to the marked answer I also came up with a two line solution from `gtools`. See my answer below.

Comment: [If you looked at the CRAN description](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gregmisc/index.html) you’d see that the package is deprecated and has been replaced by subset packages with more meaningful topic choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use mkAllStrings

```
library(Biostrings)
mkAllStrings(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 10)
```

Comment: Ah, this is perfect for those (and me) who are in the realm of bioinformatics

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate but

```
S <- c( "a", "t", "g", "c")
dd <- do.call(expand.grid,replicate(10,S,simplify=FALSE))
```

does solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update: As an alternative to the marked answer I also came up with a two line solution from gtools

```
library(gtools)
library(stringr)

get_dna_combinations <- function(lengthofsegment = 10){
## this function gets all possible combinations of the given length.
  x = permutations(n = 4, r = lengthofsegment, c('a', 't', 'c', 'g'), repeats.allowed=T)  
  ax = apply(x, 1, function(a) str_join(a, collapse=''))
  return(ax)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for longer strings, there can be a **lot** of combinations, so in case it becomes a memory problem, here's a function that generates a single sequence (which you can `Vectorize()` of course):

```
fun <- function(i, # the index of the sequence you wnat
                n, # the lengt of the sequence you want
                s){# the set of elements that make up a squence
    if(i > length(s)^n - 1)
        stop(sprintf('parameter "i" should be in the range [0,%s].',length(s)^n - 1))
    s[(i %/% length(s)^(seq(0,n-1))) %% length(s) + 1]
}
```

this returns a matrix of values (one column for each element of i)

```
FUN <- Vectorize(fun,'i')

values <- FUN(1:10,
              5,
              c('a','t','g','c'))
```

and you can get stings via:

```
apply(values,2,paste,collapse="")
```

Comment: Thanks, I've also found my own solution that I've added as an update.